# Changing the color of part of a UIView only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, colors

I have some UIView which i want to apply some effect only on part of it , so for example lets sat i have this strip UIView :

```
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];
```

Than i want to change color only on part of it in `CGRectMake(250, 0, 50, 50)];`

Is there a way to do that ?

*i don't want to put another rect above it in another color because this effect will be dynamic and change dynamically.

Thanks .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement your own UIView's method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

[Docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect%3a)

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses
>   that use technologies such as Core Graphics and UIKit to draw their
>   view’s content should override this method and implement their drawing
>   code there

You should receive something like

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect frame = self.bounds;
    // Set the background color
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    UIRectFill(frame);
    // Set the second color
    [[UIColor greenColor] set];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(250, 0, 50, 50));
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. can you please give me a simple example on how to subclass a UIView with this method and actually use it for my propose ? i am having a hard time implementing this.

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you need some additional samples please look here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=drawrect . 'drawRect' is a very popular method. There are tons of samples over the net.